# Which XML message generates an exception while doing ".LoadXml(xml_string)"?

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I'm receiving text string messages, which should be XML-like.
However, sometimes that's not the case but I don't see what those messages look like:

Current code:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
```

The Exception errormessage is quite elaborated (it mentions the wrong tags), but it does not mention the xml string itself:

```
Exception during data receiving event: [System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: ID, VM, HMS. Line 1, position 156.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at ... Information.FromString(String xml) in C:\...\Information.cs:line 40
   at ....<ExtractInformation>d__71.MoveNext() in C:\...\Extraction.cs:line 161
   at some_other_function(Byte[] data) in C:\...\Extraction.cs:line 134] 
System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: ID, VM, HMS. Line 1, position 156.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   at ... Information.FromString(String xml) in C:\...\Information.cs:line 40
   at ....<ExtractInformation>d__71.MoveNext() in C:\...\Extraction.cs:line 161
   at some_other_function(Byte[] data) in C:\...\Extraction.cs:line 134]
```

My idea was to add the xml-string to the `Exception`'s `Message` property, but this seems to be read-only:

```
public static Information FromString(string xml)
{
  var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
  try
  { 
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.Message += "[" + xml + "]"; // <= compiler error CS0200
    throw ex;
  }
```

At that depth I don't have any logging possibilities and as I'm working with a server application, I can't show something on screen.

How can I add information to this `Exception` message (or to other properties/fields of the `Exception`)?

Comment: Throwing a _new_ exception, possibly with `ex` as `InnerException`, is not an option?

Comment: 1. You can catch a more specific exception: `XmlException`. 2. The message already tells you the reason are missing closing tags. 3. Why not _LOG_ the Exception message and xml right then and there? 3. I'd suggest just using `throw;` in favor of `throw ex;` => [rethrowing an exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception) (Note the "important" section)